# WebStorm docker container recreation with every run/debugger execution

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jestjs, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I would like to ask you. Why does WebStorm recreate the docker container every time I run/debug the code through the WebStorm UI?
Is it possible to turn of this recreation?

[image]

**My setup:**
Node.js docker container with NestJS, WebStorm IDE.

Logs:

> node --require /tmp/99c34ee7-cb98-459c-80ae-2373b43a93dd/jest-intellij/lib/jest-intellij-stdin-fix.js /tmp/51fa3cc9-f4c8-4094-8194-f5b536771256/nest_app/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --colors --reporters /tmp/99c34ee7-cb98-459c-80ae-2373b43a93dd/jest-intellij/lib/jest-intellij-reporter.js --verbose --testNamePattern=^AppController (e2e) / (GET)$ --runTestsByPath /tmp/51fa3cc9-f4c8-4094-8194-f5b536771256/nest_app/test/app.e2e-spec.ts
> Container nodejs_docker_test-nodejs_test-1  Recreate
> Container nodejs_docker_test-nodejs_test-1  Recreated
> Attaching to nodejs_docker_test-nodejs_test-1
> nodejs_docker_test-nodejs_test-1  | nodejs_docker_test-nodejs_test-1  | nodejs_docker_test-nodejs_test-1  | nodejs_docker_test-nodejs_test-1  | nodejs_docker_test-nodejs_test-1  | nodejs_docker_test-nodejs_test-1  | nodejs_docker_test-nodejs_test-1  | nodejs_docker_test-nodejs_test-1  | nodejs_docker_test-nodejs_test-1  | nodejs_docker_test-nodejs_test-1  |

I tried to setup this in run/debug configuration, but without results.

EDIT:

I understand the reason for this behavior. This is mainly to prohibit any state persistence between runs and ensure a clean slate for each run/debug, thereby reducing unexpected side effects. But sometimes it can come in handy to turn off this behavior, for example, when container recreation takes quite some time.
Or when (and this is more relevant) I need to change something in the underlying container and run a test immediately after the change (for an immediate feedback loop).

Comment: Recreating a container is pretty routine; is there any particular season you don't want to here?  The screen shot suggests you might be running Compose under the hood (please [edit] the question to [include the logs as plain text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), though) and that will recreate containers as required for routine changes, including rebuilding the image.

Comment: I understand the reason for this behavior. This is mainly to prohibit any state persistence between runs and ensure a clean slate for each run/debug, thereby reducing unexpected side effects. But sometimes it can come in handy to turn off this behavior, for example, when container recreation takes quite some time.